# Start-Process gives error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Here's the code

```
$tool =  "E:\Experiments\Popup\latest\xperf.exe"
$toolOutput =  "XPerfOutput.log"
$toolError = "XPerfError.log"
$command = "-stop"


$x = Start-Process -FilePath $tool -ArgumentList $command -RedirectStandardOutput $toolOutput -RedirectStandardError $toolError -WindowStyle Hidden -PassThru -Wait
```

And Here's there error:

```
Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. At E:\Experiments\Popup\asd.ps1:9 char:1
+ Start-Process -FilePath $tool -ArgumentList $command -RedirectStandardOutput $toolOutput RedirectStandardError $toolError -WindowStyle Hidden
-PassThru -Wait
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I want to run the process in a hidden window, wait for it to return and get the error, output and exit code.

Comment: What is the value of $XPerfFolder?  You are combining $XPerfFolder to "C:\Experiment\....".  It doesn't make sense at all unless $XPerfFolder is empty.

Comment: that's fixed here now. Code is good

Comment: The particular EXE is ill-behaved when it comes to errors.  I've noticed it tends to pop UI rather than write to stderr.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [documentation for Start-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347667.aspx), the combination of the redirection parameters (RedirectStandardOutput and RedirectStandardError) and the WindowStyle parameter is invalid since they exist in separate [parameter sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878348(v=VS.85).aspx).

This means that they cannot be used together. This is why you're receiving that particular error.

Comment: @scott-saad ok, how then will i capture the error and output?

Comment: Sadly the fix is to remove -WindowStyle Hidden .  I'll file a bug against this to investigate why this is the case and fix it if possible.

Comment: This was fixed in PowerShell v.3.  But, on legacy Windows machines e.g. Windows 7 (which shipped with v.2), you're out of luck.